# Printing a html5 canvas element

Tags: printing, html5-canvas

How can I print a html5 canvas element that has some content drawn on it using javascript? My print preview shows a blank box instead of the contents in the canvas element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the contents of the canvas in an image tag, you will be able to print the image.